# Addition of tow list with different list lengthes

Tags: list, python-3.x

I am trying to remove the strings from a list and then find the sum of the new list with a list which has smaller length.

I have written a code which does not work at 3-4 places. I have some question,
why does the if statement does not work propely?
How can I write the addition function for this kind of list with differnt lenght?

This is my code:

```
def remove_text_from_list(the_list):
    z = []
    for x in the_list:
        if isinstance(x, float):
            z.append(x)
            return z


def add(a,b):
    return a+b

x = []
list1=['s', 1.0, 2.0, 'a', 3.0, 4.0,'b', 5.0, 6.0,'c', 7.0, 8.0]
list2=[10.0, 20.0]
newlist=remove_text_from_list(list1)
for i in newlist:
    for j in list2:
        f = add(i,j)
        final_list.append(f)
print(x)
```

The desired result should be like following:

```
final_list=[11,22,13,24,15,26,17,28]
```

Comment: What is it you are expecting `remove_test_from_list` to do, and what is it doping instead?

Answer (score 2):

Use a generator expression to create a generator that yields floats from `list1`.  Use `itertools.cycle` to iterate over `list2` repeatedly as needed.  Use `zip` to pair the floats from `list1` with the cycled items from `list2` and add them together in a list comprehension.

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> just_floats = (i for i in list1 if isinstance(i, float))
>>> [a+b for a, b in zip(just_floats, cycle(list2))]
[11.0, 22.0, 13.0, 24.0, 15.0, 26.0, 17.0, 28.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You return the list in the if-statement. If you do it at the end of the for-loop it should work:

```
def remove_text_from_list(the_list):
    z = []
    for x in the_list:
        if isinstance(x, float):
            z.append(x)
    return z
```

But still x will not be your expected `final_result` but:

```
x = [11.0, 21.0, 12.0, 22.0, 13.0, 23.0, 14.0, 24.0, 15.0, 25.0, 16.0, 26.0, 17.0, 27.0, 18.0, 28.0]
```